# Меню с пролистыванием пунктов как пролистывание вкладок в браузере FireFox

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Необходимо реализовать появление кнопок пролистывания пунктов меню при открытии нескольких пунктов, если они занимают более одной строки. как на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е.,

1. Кнопки пролистывания (стрелки) изначально — с классом `hidden`.
2. Если элементы списка `li` занимают больше одной строки, то кнопки пролистывания (влево, вправо) появляются — добавляем класс `show`.
3. При нажатии на стрелки (влево, вправо) элементы списка `li` пролистываются в рамках одной строки (т.е. они не переносятся на другую строку).
4. Элементы списка `li` скрываются слева или справа при нажатии на стрелки

Главный вопрос, как отследить что элементы списка заняли больше одной строки, чтобы появились кнопки влево/вправо?

уточняю вопрос: ширина элемента списка li всегда разная, элементы списка подгружаются динамически с ajax. т.е. надо как-то вычислять ширину элемента li. Вот такой код у меня

```js
/*multiselection*/
(function() {
  function Slideshow(element) {
    this.el = document.querySelector(element);
    this.init();
  }
  Slideshow.prototype = {
    init: function() {
      this.wrapper = this.el.querySelector(".slider-wrapper");
      this.previous = this.el.querySelector(".slider-previous");
      this.next = this.el.querySelector(".slider-next");
      this.index = 0;

      this.recalculate();

      this.actions();
    },
    recalculate: function() {
      this.slides = this.el.querySelectorAll('.slide');
      this.total = this.slides.length;
    },
    _slideTo: function(slide) {
      var currentSlide = this.slides[slide];
      this.wrapper.style.left = "-" + currentSlide.offsetLeft + "px";
    },
    actions: function() {
      var self = this;
      self.next.addEventListener("click", function() {
        self.index++;
        self.previous.style.display = "block";
        if (self.index == self.total - 1) {
          self.index = self.total - 1;
          self.next.style.display = "none";
        }
        self._slideTo(self.index);
      }, false);
      self.previous.addEventListener("click", function() {
        self.index--;
        self.next.style.display = "block";
        if (self.index == 0) {
          self.index = 0;
          self.previous.style.display = "none";
        }
        self._slideTo(self.index);
      }, false);

      $(document).on('order:service:tabs:add', function() {
        console.log('tab added');
      });
      $(document).on('request:service:tab:close', function() {
        console.log('tab closed');
      })
    }
  };
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var slider = new Slideshow("#multiSelection");
  });
})();
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 730px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider-wrapper {
  width: 9999px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 500ms linear;
}
.slide {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
.slider-nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider" id="multiSelection">
  <ul class="slider-wrapper nav nav-tabs js_order_service_tabs">
    <li class="slide"></li>
    <li class="slide"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="slider-nav">
    <div id="moveMenuLeft" class="icon-wrap-style-left slider-previous">
      <i class="icon icon-chevron-left icon-position-left "></i>
    </div>
    <div id="moveMenuRight" class="icon-wrap-style-right slider-next">
      <i class="icon icon-chevron-right icon-position-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8hjqfuq/)

Comment: прочитайте мой пример еще раз, там нет привязки к ширине li, или ul

Comment: У нас тут есть встроенный аналог jsfiddle. Пожалуйста, не стеснятесь его использовать ))

Comment: у меня не получается его корректно отобразить...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример с использованием `JQUERY`:

```
/*HTML*/
<div>
  <ul>
  <li>menu1</li>
  <li>menu2</li>
  <li>menu3</li>
  <li>menu4</li>
  <li>menu5</li>
  <li>menu6</li>
  <li>menu7</li>
  </ul>
</div>

/*CSS*/
div>ul>li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:10px
}
div {
  width:300px;
}
div>ul{
  position:absolute;
}

/*JS*/  
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('ul').width() > $('div').width())   
    alert('меню шире родительского блока');
});
```

Посмотреть здесь http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrxwvB

Comment: уточнила вопрос

Comment: ширину li можно вычислить по аналогии $('li').width();